# Find index of element in a List

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

I have an List and I am trying to find if there is any "DishId" with value 63 and if found , i wanted to return the object count of the element, for example here I wanted to return 1 as it is the first object in the list.
Below is the list :

```
  result =  [ TextRow {
        BagId: 'BTWDCZ46826',
        BagStatus: 1,
        DishId: 63,
        SellerId: 205,
        Qty: 1,
        PreperationTime: 240 
        } ,
        {
        BagId: 'BTWDCZ46234',
        BagStatus: 1,
        DishId: 69,
        SellerId: 195,
        Qty: 1,
        PreperationTime: 150 
        } 
    ]
```

Below is the code that I tried to find if DishId with 63 is found or not

```
if(results.find(({ DishId }) => dishId === req.body.dishId)){
       index = results.indexOf(({ DishId }) => x.dishId === req.body.dishId).DishId;
       console.log("Found");
       console.log("Index is ", index);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the Index not the object found itself, So use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) instead of [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
const arr = [{
    BagId: 'BTWDCZ46826',
    BagStatus: 1,
    DishId: 63,
    SellerId: 205,
    Qty: 1,
    PreperationTime: 240
  },
  {
    BagId: 'BTWDCZ46234',
    BagStatus: 1,
    DishId: 69,
    SellerId: 195,
    Qty: 1,
    PreperationTime: 150
  }
]
console.log(arr.findIndex(({
  DishId
}) => DishId === 63))
```

> I wanted to return 1 as it is the first object

*It gonna return 0 not 1, since array in `JS` are zero based*

Answer (score 0):

```js
const result = [{
        BagId: 'BTWDCZ46826',
        BagStatus: 1,
        DishId: 63,
        SellerId: 205,
        Qty: 1,
        PreperationTime: 240 
        } ,
        {
        BagId: 'BTWDCZ46234',
        BagStatus: 1,
        DishId: 69,
        SellerId: 195,
        Qty: 1,
        PreperationTime: 150 
        } 
    ];

const idx = result.findIndex(el => el.DishId === 69);
console.log(idx);
```

Also, there was an error in your result array.
Btw, findIndex returns -1 if searched element is not present. See [findIndex MDN Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex?retiredLocale=tr)